# Bootstrap - Why my scrollspy is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I've never used scrollspy in my project and I need to know how it works. I have seen the documentation from the bootstrap page, some other stackoverflow questions and youtube videos.

I have this code:

For the nav:

```
<!-- Start nav -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Brand"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>-->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar">
                <li><a href="#Inicio">Incio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#NuestrosServicios">Nuestros Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portafolio">Portafolio</a></li>

                <!--<li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#Inicio">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#NuestrosServicios">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Portafolio">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>-->
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    <!-- End nav -->
```

For the body:

```
<!-- Body container -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 menu-1" id="Inicio"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 menu-2" id="NuestrosServicios"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 menu-3" id="Portafolio"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Body container -->
```

The JavaScript side:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").scrollspy({target: "#navbar"});
});
```

The full example in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yotamorila/edit?output/):

Answer (score 0):

The target should indicate to the element id. In your navbar element I don't see the id attribute. Try adding id to the navbar.

Also add the `position: relative;` css to your body element.

if the above didn't fix the issue use the data attribute like this `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example"` in the body tag instead of javascript and don't forget the id attribute for the navbar element.

Comment: My element ID is on the `ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right`, please check the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yotamorila/1/edit?html,output). Thank you for your answer.